# could you help me to fix this? it's always getting error everytime I run, i didn't understand why

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I made this code eaxactly like how my teacher make it, but I didnt use like application simply like neatbeans. I use a java online from jdoodle.com, and when I try the code like how my teacher do like this code :

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class UTS {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        String judul = "Penghitung Promo Toko Roti";

        System.out.println(" "+judul);
        System.out.print("Masukkan umur customer : ");

        int umur = s.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Masukkan berat badan customer : ");

        int beratBadan = s.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Masukkan total belanja customer : ");
        int totalBelanja = s.nextInt();
        int potongan = 0;
        if (totalBelanja > 50000 && umur > 16) {
            //kondisi true
            int persentasePotongan = 0;
            if (umur <= 25) {
                persentasePotongan = beratBadan / 10;
            } else if (umur <= 50) {
                persentasePotongan = beratBadan / 5;
            } else {
                persentasePotongan = beratBadan / 2;
            }

            potongan = totalBelanja * persentasePotongan / 100;
            System.out.println("Selamat anda mendapatkan potongan "+persentasePotongan+
                           "% dari Rp "+totalBelanja+ " sebesar Rp "+potongan);
        } else {
            //kondisi false
            System.out.println("Mohon maaf, anda belum mendapatkan promo");
        }

        int totalHarusBayar = totalBelanja - potongan;
        System.out.print(*\n------------------------------*);
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("Umur : "+umur+ " Tahun");
        System.out.println("Berat Badan : "+beratBadan+ "Kg");
        System.out.println("Total Belanja : Rp "+totalBelanja);
        System.out.println("Potongan Promo : Rp "+potongan);
        System.out.println("Total Harus Bayar : Rp "+totalHarusBayar);
    }
}
```

and when I run, the output it's getting error like this :

```
/UTS.java:32: error: illegal start of expression
System.out.print(*\n------------------------------*);
                         ^
/UTS.java:32: error: illegal character: '\'
System.out.print(*\n------------------------------*);
                          ^
/UTS.java:32: error: illegal start of expression
System.out.print(*\n------------------------------*);
                                                           ^
/UTS.java:32: error: not a statement
System.out.print(*\n------------------------------*);
                                                          ^
4 errors
```

for sure, its like my teacher code exatcly but for me it's error. can someone help me?

Comment: You are missing quotation marks. Carefully read the error message, is telling you exactly where.

Answer (score 1):

Printing a statement which isn't a variable is must be inside inverted commas.

```
System.out.print(*\n------------------------------*);
```

should be like below

```
System.out.println("*");
System.out.print("------------------------------*");
```

System.out.println() goes to a new line after printing.